# Why typing something in a TextField outputs Picker: the selection "0" is invalid

Tags: swiftui

In iOS15 the following code was working fine, now in iOS16 I get a warning next to `ForEach(1 ..< maxMonths)` that reads as follow...

> Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal

I fixed this warning by adding adding `id: \.self` to the forEach, `ForEach(1 ..< maxMonths, id: \.self)`.

But now every time I type something on the `inputTaskName` field, I get the following output message in the `Debug Console.

> Picker: the selection "0" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.

Any idea why typing something in the TextField outputs that message?

#### Original Code, which was running fine in iOS15.

```
struct PickerTest: View {
    @State private var monthsPickerValue = 0
    @State private var inputTaskName:String = ""
    let maxMonths = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Task Name", text:$inputTaskName)
            
            Picker("", selection: $monthsPickerValue) {
                ForEach(1 ..< maxMonths) {
                    
                    if $0 == 1{
                        Text("Repeats every "  + String($0) + " month ")
                    }else{
                        Text("Repeats every "  + String($0) + " months ")
                    }
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing `monthsPickerValue` to something other than 0 fixed the issue, in my case, I changed it to 1 `@State private var monthsPickerValue = 1`.

```
struct PickerTest: View {
    @State private var monthsPickerValue = 1
    @State private var inputTaskName:String = ""
    let maxMonths = 20
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Task Name", text:$inputTaskName)
            
            Picker("", selection: $monthsPickerValue) {
                Text("No Option").tag(Optional<String>(nil))
                
                ForEach(1 ..< maxMonths, id: \.self) {
                    if $0 == 1{
                        Text("Repeats every "  + String($0) + " month ")
                    }else{
                        Text("Repeats every "  + String($0) + " months ")
                    }
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}
```